# For a type defined as a map of enum values to strings, how to check with flow that the map object literal has a key for every enum value?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype, typechecking

Let's say I have this type

```
type Status = "draft" | "validated" | "private" | "available" | "archived";
```

I'm instantiating objects that map this enum type to a string:

```
const statusNameMap: { [Status]: string } = {
  "draft": "Draft",
  "validated": "Validated",
  "private": "Private",
  "available": "Available",
  "archived": "Archived",
};
```

This works just fine. Now the question is, how do I check at the type level that the object literal has to contain as keys all of the values from the `Status` enum?

The main motivation is that the `Status` type is not in my control really, that's code being generated from introspecting a GraphQL schema, while the object map is for presentation purposes. If an enum value gets added/removed, I would like Flow to complain about my object literal not having the right keys.

Is this possible with Flow at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

No - at least not in the way you'd like.
As far as I know this is not supported and has been a great deal of stress for me.

However, you can use `$ObjMap` to probably get what you want.

```
const MyEnumValues = Object.freeze({
  KEY_A: 'VALUE_A', 
  KEY_B: 'VALUE_B', 
  KEY_C: 'VALUE_C', 
});
const Test8: $Exact<$ObjMap<typeof MyEnumValues, () => string>> = ({
    'KEY_A': '',
    'KEY_B': '',
    //'KEY_C': '', // Errors here!
});
```

Resulting in a type that maybe looks like this under the hood:

```
$Exact<$ObjMap<typeof MyEnumValues, () => string>> = {|
  KEY_A: string,
  KEY_B: string,
  KEY_C: string,
|}
```

So kindof. If your keys and values are the same then this is probably exactly what you want but its still frustrating.

Here are my test cases I was running to obtain a simple Enum set to Value set [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcwBjOAOwGdiBZATwFFyBXAWwDUBDGZjSsALxgA8gCMAVhhKEAdFHwYMALwwAKAN6owYANIMAmgH0AggC4wAcnbGAMgFUGJiwBowW3QcMAhc1dsPvFzdtPSMAYV9re0cwoNQAXwBKAG50bDwiMEI6HAwweiY2QTAAEi4ePgAebNy4KHzGFg5uXkoAPlSavIYsTmkCpppOHGKSnr7CSvUAHzAAagBtAGsMOnMBtgBdc2p8AEtyAHMwafiO1GBgMAA5YQAVBnNrxQATfjHe6TBREiyACwwCn4nHIcEIAPw32YxwheQAtGAKDA6GBmJQDscAAbTTFgF5wPjkCzEBAEJYyC5XbTUsAAZUIexgMDxBMoROIrGGiPIGDhhDgcIoGFQZCoxDufEIAEZzON+o02EMRkJNDSFhtmhVKDJQiZtpYXO5tJcbvdHnS-nBmDAXmBAfgCDInQlUia5cR0jA9iQ9sQ4BIpMQvYRAdwsjlhaLqGAJdQAEyyz6EDVK4oaI1gdUKzWtHWeYz6iyGmkm24Pcy0y3W232x3OpKUsA9HBen1+gNfTkjLoUqPiyUAZnMJTE4iVU1mnHMUtconMcZO8VcqkSgjaYF2GPXQnTNKnBucGbnBozpbN5gA6sIAEo6WlgOHrnokDA4YjgzjEOhWsB-TgANzyfkwAAIgUF4MCgA4MBA8MgIjMBOEOTgDidCkGzdXBW19O0kzALtEQ7INfVDZkezAVQenfCNEhFCho1jQgABZh3dSoRwkcd3RTYZl1XAR103I42m3CjVWpLNChzPg8yMAtfGLakz3LC0rRtO18AdfA0ISWjMJbb0cP9SROy5YzAzAYNSPDXJe3o-tqAAVmHUdxxmTMNX1ITjlOPi1w3Qh9mEtNxONK4y3NSs1JrTS63QvSrlTKBmHIaQ9goGyMDssUY0lAA2NN4DgJZmBwdZs0SUAAqC44EUoThWDyBBfT+XCDLbZArgEsBQo3ZrCBIVrVCKkqcFXXqaRIThKDyDVylzXUzAzGkaQUQhmHwcgDVSFbqSmmaGik+aZN1Hxlt2sA1o2raix2i7lMiqt1NrbTnQusATV2u4I0oEh9jfS7XwIQh+BA0FiG4ZkyAgsAcE-P5+CuzbELAf8WhgjN4gSRtm2wjkuR7OicsYgB2dZhkqDVXG80SeSQJVVAWU9wvPMAAAUHVEThRGRDcnpedkNK0qESWm384BwDEwBw0lqwpTYUhxrDDPx7sENUUJ72Ea4bH0RJsoYyUAA5WKTdjXIpro6kOppjsoPzupp0Td2pCxFosBTDxpN3PC8D2D2Zn3wn9otXBNfQGFpABCXTkiAA).
I also included the code here in case try flow ever goes offline.

```
/* @flow */

export const MyEnumValues = Object.freeze({
  KEY_A: 'VALUE_A', 
  KEY_B: 'VALUE_B', 
  KEY_C: 'VALUE_C', 
});

export type MyEnum = $Values<typeof MyEnumValues>;
type ExactMyEnumMap = $Exact<{| +[key: MyEnum]: string |}>;
// NOTE: Needs $Exact bc theres another bug here - only using `|` doesn't work.
//       Still doesn't map one-to-one
const Test1: ExactMyEnumMap = {
    [MyEnumValues.KEY_A]: '',
    // NOTE: Should error...
};
// Exact explicit object literal type
const Test2: ExactMyEnumMap = ({
    [MyEnumValues.KEY_A]: '',
    // NOTE: Should error...
})
// Explicit object map type.
const Test3: $ObjMap<{| a: 1, b: 2 |}, () => string> = ({
    a: '',
    b: ''
    // NOTE: WORKS -> Except that you have to "redefine" tye type again...
})
// Explicit exact map object literal type. (Ext type)
const Test4: $Exact<$ObjMap<ExactMyEnumMap, () => string>> = ({
    [MyEnumValues.KEY_A]: '',
    // NOTE: Should error...
})
// Explicit object map object literal type.
const Test5: $ObjMap<{| [MyEnum]: string |}, () => string> = ({
    // NOTE: Should error...
})
// Map function type.
const Test6 = (lookup: MyEnum)/* string - same with explicit */ => {
    switch (lookup) {
        case MyEnumValues.KEY_A:
            return '';
        case MyEnumValues.KEY_B:
            return '';
        // NOTE: Should error...
        //       Typescript reports "not all code paths return a value"
    }
}
// Explicit map type.
const Test7: Map<MyEnum, string> = new Map([
    // NOTE: Probably shouldn't error but was hoping it would.
]);
// Explicit map type (KEYS ONLY).
const Test8: $Exact<$ObjMap<typeof MyEnumValues, () => string>> = ({
    'KEY_A': '',
    'KEY_B': '',
    //'KEY_C': '', // YES!
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use exact type for this case and define type with {| ... |}
It will looks like

```
 const statusNameMap: { [Status]: string } = {|
  "draft": "Draft",
  "validated": "Validated",
  "private": "Private",
  "available": "Available",
  "archived": "Archived",
|};
```

Comment: The expression after `=` has to be a value expression, while `{| ... |}` is a type expression, so this is actually can't be parsed by Flow.